# Order MySQL query by multiple ids

Tags: php, mysql

I have problems sorting results from MySQL. Here is the code:

```
$my_query = "
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1, tbl2, tbl3 
WHERE tbl1.id = tbl2.id2 
  AND tbl1.sub_id = tbl3.sub_id 
  AND tbl1.id IN(22, 55, 5, 10, 40, 2001, 187)
";
```

This query works fine, but when I print it, it's ordered by tbl1.id ASC. I want to display the same order as I used in `IN(22,55,5,10,40,2001,187)`.

I think it is possible, but I tried my best and did not get it fixed. Is there any solution that works for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this ORDER BY clause that uses the [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function to get the order you want:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(tbl1.id, 22, 55, 5, 10, 40, 2001, 187)
```